# Managed Package error emails behaviour changed?

Tags: managed-package, error, isv, second-generation-packaging, 2gp-ama

I have a First-Generation Managed Package that was updated and released for years. It's current version is 6.0.

I just recent added a User to the Package page to get error notifications as described in [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_notification_set.htm). As the documentation clearly states and how it worked for years of my own experience:

> Notifications are sent only for package versions that are uploaded
> after the address is added.

BUT, one day after I added this address and not even uploaded a package version, I received error emails  from old package version and real customer orgs.

1. Did Salesforce change the behaviour of this recently?
2. Does this also apply to Second-Generation Packages where Salesforce just recently [enabled this feature](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_sfdx_packaging_set_error_notification.htm&release=228&type=5)?

Comment: This sounds like a new case question for the SF support people. Could not find anything different than you. Maybe something have changed in recent releases.